# Can't connect to redis when deploying redis on openshift

Tags: docker, redis, openshift

I try to add a redis application by openshift from image `quay/bitnami/redis` or `docker.io/library/redis`. When starting up, it will create route for external access, for example `xx.com`.

Then I connect it by `redis-cli -h xx.com`, but it failed with error msg: `Error 10060 connecting to xx.com`.

Any help?

Comment: Routes are only available for HTTP(S) traffic. If you need external TCP access, you should expose Redis through a "LoadBalancer" type Service https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer

Comment: You should post this as an answer rather than comment

Answer (score 1):

Routes are only available for HTTP(S) traffic. If you need external TCP access, you should expose Redis through a "LoadBalancer" type Service https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer